# microsoft translator doesn't translates to kannada language

Tags: microsoft-translator

I did not get the kannada language in microsoft translator. I was about translate my english content in word document to kannada. But the language is not in the list. It is very sad that a language spoken by more than 50 million native speakers.
I request you to add the language in the translation list. And enable us to provide service in Kannada language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Microsoft support. If you have complaints about their products, contact them.

Answer (score 1):

We are periodically adding new languages and language features to the Translator service.

You can learn more about how we add new languages and language features here: https://microsofttranslator.uservoice.com/forums/421776-how-do-i-get-my-language-supported

Best regards,
Gwenda
Microsoft Translator Team